# What is the right way of getting binary predictions?

Tags: arrays, numpy, keras

I'm making an array using numpy from the prediction of a deep learning model as follows.

```
predictions = model.predict(X_val_prep)
predictions = [1 if x > 0.5 else 0 for x in predictions]
```

But it shows error:

```
Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I rewrite my code?

Comment: what's the shape of `predictions`?  2d?  What is `x`, e.g. `predictions[0]`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an array to condition.
Try using

```
numpy.where(predictions > 0.5,1,0)
```